# Why does a floated left div intersect with a left-fixed div?

Tags: html, css

I have a fixed div on the left of my screen and I want to put there the categories, and near it I want to put 2 more other divs, the first one to wider that the second, and both of them to be floated left, but the problem is that the 2 divs intersect with the fixed one, and I don't want that, how can I solve this ?
I've made a fiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/rn11jxh2/

HTML:

```
<div id="meniu">
     <div id="cat" >
      <div class="catico">
        <img src="img/Categories.png"/>
      </div>
         <div class="cattext">
          Categories:
         </div>
      </div>
      <ul> 

            <li>sdncsldncsd </li>
    <li>sdncsldncsd </li><li>sdncsldncsd </li><li>sdncsldncsd </li><li>sdncsldncsd </li><li>sdncsldncsd </li><li>sdncsldncsd </li>



      </ul>       

    </div>
   <div id="invitapemail">

              </div>




   #invitapemail {
float:left;
position:relative;
height:200px;
width:620px;
right:30px;
background-color:white;
border:2px solid #797979;
border-radius:1em;
padding:10px;
margin-top:10px;
font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size:1.2em;
color:#797979;
z-index:2; 
}
#meniu{
 position:fixed;
 height:420px;
 width:140px;
 line-height:30px;
 font-size:1.15em;
 margin-left:0px;
 padding-right:75px;
 padding-left:30px;
 text-decoration:none;}
```

Comment: Hmm, so would you like to leave which div as fixed and other as what? I didn't quite get that part.

Comment: The first div to remain fix and have the same position no matter if you scroll and the second div that has float left to be near the fixed div (not over the fixed div)

Comment: Probably not the best solution, but at least they don't conflict: #menu: z-index: 3 | or | #invitapemail: position: fixed; margin-top: 300px;

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior. `position:fixed` removes the element from the document flow. That means it will ignore other elements as if they aren't even there, this it can cause overlaps. The `float:left` is shifting your content over to the left as if the fixed menu isn't there.

You can set a `margin-left` to offset the elements by the width+padding of the menu, in this case it looks like 200px: https://jsfiddle.net/rn11jxh2/1/

You can read more about positioning and floats here: https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/